# WCF net.tcp service and stored assembly in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, sqlclr, net.tcp

I have a simple client of WCF service which works with `net.tcp` protocol. This client should be added to database as stored assembly.

From service config:

```
<service name="ServiceDocument.DocService" behaviorConfiguration="TCPServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="DocServiceTCP" address="net.tcp://localhost:5430/DocService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpConfig" contract="ServiceDoc.IDocService"/>
        <endpoint name="DocServiceMex" address="net.tcp://localhost:5431/mexDocService" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

I added to the client service reference used address `net.tcp://localhost:5431/mexDocService` and then client is working fine.

Service reference generated code like:

```
namespace DocContent.DocServiceTCP {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]  
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Document", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceDoc")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class Document {
    ....
```

But when I try to add this client to the database as stored assembly(using SMSS) then I'm getting an error like:

> assembly system.runtime.serialization was not found in the sql catalog

Before add assembly I run:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DBNAME TO SYSTEM_USER
```

As described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) `system.runtime.serialization` is not supported in SQL Server.

How can I add the assembly to the database in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQLCLR was designed as an alternative to implmenting complex stored procedures/functions/triggers etc in raw SQL.

It was not designed to host a full-featured .net runtime.

It was certainly not designed to execute code which opens up local tcp sockets and tries to transmit data across to somewhere.

Even if you could do this, in my opinion you should not. Some concerns should be kept separate from each other and this is one example. Apologies if this sounds prescriptive but I have experience of using both SQLCLR and WCF and I struggle to think of any upside to combining them into the same layer in the stack.

If you need to integrate to .net code from your SQL database, there are other options, such as [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx). This will allow you to trigger a service call from .net code by listening for database changes.

If you want to send data to other SQL server instances then there is [Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for answer. When I use Web reference in the client then I can add assembly. So, I thought that Service reference should also import as assembly. I'm going to read about SqlDependency and Broker. Thanks

Comment: @MegaTron you are correct in that service reference can be compiled into an assembly and added. When you add an assembly to SQLCLR the dll manifest is read and any dependencies are checked before the assembly can be added. The service reference depends on System.Runtime.Serialization as you have found out. SQL has no need to be dependent on this assembly, and nor should it.